# Is it legal to use variadic templates in operator overloading?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

I would like to be able to write something along these lines:

```
struct bar {};

template <typename ... Args>
bar operator+(bar, Args ...)
{}
```

I just checked with clang/gcc and the overloaded operator is picked up both by binary expressions (`a+b`) and unary expressions (`+a`), as I would expect. However operators are more restricted than normal functions, in the sense that - for instance - you cannot overload `operator+()` with three arguments.

Is the usage above legal and portable?

**EDIT** To give a bit of context, I am clearly not expecting to be able to define variadic operators or anything of the sort. The reason I am interested in this is for a ugly hack: I would like to make some operators variadic so that I can "override" them with other non-variadic implementations. Since variadic templates are considered to be less specialised than non-variadic templates in the function template overloading rules, I could override a variadic operator with a non-variadic one. Yes it's pretty horrid :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the definition fine, because there exist valid specializations with non-empty packs<sup>1</sup>.

Now, specific expressions `a+b` or `+a` are i.a. transformed into non-member calls of the form `operator+(a, b)` and `operator+(a)`, respectively ([[over.match.oper]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#2)). Name lookup then finds the operator function template, whose specialization becomes part of the candidates. Finally, [[over.match.oper]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#6) just delegates to overload resolution as usual:

> The set of candidate functions for overload resolution is the union of
>   the member candidates, the non-member candidates, and the built-in
>   candidates. **The argument list contains all of the operands of the
>   operator. The best function from the set of candidate functions is
>   selected according to 13.3.2 and 13.3.3.**

Your code will also work as intended, since overload resolution and partial ordering will respect the operator function template like all others.

---

<sup>1</sup> declaring the above for unary operators, except perhaps postfix `--` and `++`, is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Cf. [[temp.res]/(8.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added a bit of context to the original question.

Comment: @bluescarni Yeah, that's all fine.

Answer (score 3):

The standard restricts the number of arguments (and the presence of default arguments) for *operator function*s, in [**[over.oper]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper):

> 8 - An operator function cannot have default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]), except where explicitly stated below. Operator
>   functions cannot have more or fewer parameters than the number required for the corresponding operator,
>   as described in the rest of this subclause.

However, what you have declared is an *operator function template*, which has no such restrictions. This means that your code is fine; the use of unary or binary `+` will be transformed into a call to `operator+` with one or two arguments and an appropriate instantiation of your template will be generated accordingly.

It would be illegal if you were to specialize or explicitly instantiate the operator function template with an illegal number of arguments, since (**[over.oper]**):

> 1 - [...] A specialization of an operator function template is also an operator
>   function. [...]

---

Note that a similar effect obtains if we write a non-variadic operator function template that can be instantiated with incorrect types:

```
template<class T> int operator+(T, T) { return 0; }  // OK
struct bar {}; template int operator+(bar, bar);     // OK
template int operator+(int, int);                    // Error is here
```